# select option from database display to another page

Tags: php, html, css, phpmyadmin

Please help me how to display this select option dropdown to another page.
i got the correct content of the database and when i submit the button the one that it display if always the first row or (default).
PLEASE.

```
$select_size = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM size_tbl WHERE prod_id ='$prod_aydi' ");
?>  
Size: &nbsp; <select class="details_order1" name="size" >
<?php
while($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($select_size))
{
    $prod_diay = $data['prod_id'];
    $sze = $data['size_name'] ;
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $prod_diay ?>"><?php echo $sze ?></option>
    <?php
}
?>
</select>
```

**FUNCTION.php**

```
function get_size($pid) {
    $result=mysql_query("select id from product_tbl where id='$pid' ") ;
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);    
    $aydi = $row['id'];

    $sel = mysql_query("SELECT size_name FROM size_tbl WHERE prod_id='$aydi' ");
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sel);            
    return $row2['size_name'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the "selected" attribute to the `<option>` that you want to be selected when the page loads.

```
<option selected>...</option>
```

Comment: hello. can i use $_POST in function.php ? in order to get the what i select in select option

Comment: Yes you can, if the form is submitted via POST (has method="post" in the <form> tag).

Answer (score 0):

```
<option value="<?php echo $prod_diay ?>" <?php if($sze == '$row2['size_name'] ') 
echo" selected ";  ?> >
<?php echo $sze ?></option>
```

would give you the selected option , ie like if you are doing an update or something.

Comment: can i call the $sze? it is from another file. i also try the $_POST and nothing happens